# ubuntu after rotating 3000 of addr interface goes of for 15 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, ifconfig, s3proxy

I have ~2000 ipv6 addresses on 1 interface.

While rotating them, I delete old ones and add new ones

```
for i in $(cat ip.list);do ip -6 addr del $i dev enp1s0f0;done
for i in $(cat ip.list);do ip -6 addr add $i dev enp1s0f0;done
```

after that, all connections are disconnected (`ssh/http/proxy/ping`) for ~15 seconds and after that restore by itself.

Are there some solutions?

I tried to execute few scripts continuously, with 300-500 addresses each, but it didn't help.